# Successfully compiled resources are not displayed in the production environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

After compiling assets in production, old assets are displayed instead of new assets. Moreover, the compilation was successful and the file with the new assets is present on the server. I tried running `rake assets:clean`, it didn't help.
What could be the problem and how can it be solved?

I tried running `rake assets:clean`, it didn't help.

Comment: Have you checked if its a caching issue? It doesn't matter if new files were generated if your HTML still links to the old fingerprint digests.

Comment: no, I haven't checked, tell me how can I check it?

Comment: Request the page in your browser and use the web inspector to see what files its loading and compare the assets digests to the latest versions on the file system. While you're at it check the cache control headers and if the page is being fetched from your production server or maybe even a CDN.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/ and https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/network_monitor/. Its pretty similar in other browsers.

Comment: now the oldest existing file is loaded, and - (disk cache) is displayed in the size column in the inspector. As I understand it, assets are loaded from the cache?

Comment: Thats kind of a complex question. Browsers will load css, images, js etc from the cache if allowed by the cache directive - which is typically a good thing. But it does pose a problem when you deploy new versions of assets. Rails uses a tried and true trick which is to add a random digest to each file name as a cache busting mechanism. But that only works when your HTML links to the latest version of the file.

Comment: As to why its failing - either your Rails app isn't generating the correct HTML or the browser is using old cached html. There can be a lot of reasons why this can happen - I worked on one app where someone though it was a good idea to fragment cache the entire `<head>` section.

Comment: I'm not using pure HTML, but what ActiveAdmin provides. The HTML itself that generates AA is displayed correctly, but the old styles are loaded